# What is the difference between writing multiple dataflows and combining via datamart versus connect to data source via data mart?

Tags: powerbi

I'm exploring power bi data flows and data marts.

Data flow allow to connect to data source.

Data mart also allows to connect to data source and even to data flows.

What is the benefit of having data flows and connecting to them via data mart versus directly using datamart to connect to data source?

Comment: Which connection did you end up choosing? I'm in the same situation as you and I'm not sure which one to choose. I'm leaning towards Data Source -> Dataflow -> Datamart instead of Data Source -> Datamart, mainly to take advantage of the built-in machine learning capabilities of dataflows, in case I need them in the future. Have you considered anything else that could help make the decision?

Comment: Not explored data mart or data flows yet

Answer (score 0):

A Data Flow uses Power Query to copy data into a Data Lake in .CSV format.

A Data Mart uses Power Query to copy data into a relational database where it's stored in a highly-compressed columnstore.

> What is the benefit of having data flows and connecting to them via data mart versus directly using datamart to connect to data source?

So this is essentially the same question as whether to load a data warehouse directly, or to load a Data Lake first, and load the warehouse from there.

The data would be available for other uses.  So you might copy the raw data with a Data Flow, and then transform while loading into a Datamart.  Another user might use that same raw data to build a Dataset.

On the other hand, it's an additional copy of the data, and you've got two refreshes to worry about.

Comment: Two refreshes if not using the data flow? Even if I use data flow then data mart and dataset need refreshing so there are rei refreshes required plus third fir dataflow itself. Or do you mean refresh from source db?